# HashMap for holding tokens from arbitrary number of files

Tags: java, oop

I have a piece of code which is supposed to read arbitrary number of files and tokenize their content into a `HashMap`, however when I try to run the code it always overwrites the `HashMap` with the contents of the last file read. The class definition is as follows:

```
 public class Test {
       HashMap<String, Integer> tokens;
       public Test(file, int, int){
       }
       public void start(){
            read();
            displayOutput();
       }
       private void read(){
            file[] files = inDir.listFiles();
            for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                File file = new File(files[i].getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                .........
                tokens = gettokens(file);
            }             
       }
       private HashMap<String, Integer> getokens(File infile) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> fileTokens = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            BufferedReader in;
            ...........
            ...........
            filetokens.put(..);
            ............... 
            ...............
            ...............
            return fileTokens;
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test obj = new Test(arg[0],arg[1],arg[2]);
            obj.start();
       }
}
```

I think the problem is that when fileTokens returns the tokens variable is overwritten. Hence I only see tokens from the last file read in the directory. My question is is there any way to avoid overwriting the tokens variable without using `putAll`? i.e. I dont want to do this tokens.putAll(gettokens(file));.

Comment: Is there a reason not to pass the same map in as a parameter?

Comment: `putAll` is exactly for this, but you can go with your own implementation for sure.

Comment: actually i am not supposed to modify the main function. So i dont think passing the map as parameter will work, I was hoping there is some oop concept that i might be missing that could help me achieve the desired functionality. Is there anyway that to declare tokens variable so that it does not get overwritten ?

Comment: You can use `tokens` in your `getTokens` method instead of `filetokens`, then you don't need to return anything from the `getTokens`

Comment: that's not real Java (e.g. constructor arguments are missing types). make sure your code compiles

Comment: @RameezSaleem No, there is no such OOP concept. `tokens = gettokens(file);` this exactly means that you assigning new value to the variable tokens every time you run this line.

Comment: but that's what you wrote: in `read()`, you keep reading every files, and for each file read, you replace `tokens`.  After all the readings are done, you then display `tokens`, which of course only contains content of last file read.  You may want to double think what is the correct behavior you are looking for

Comment: Do you want to put tokens of all files into the same map? or you want to read and display each file separately?

Comment: *I dont want to do this tokens.putAll(gettokens(file));* Why??

Comment: @shmosel I just wanted to know if there was another way of doing it without using the putAll method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your `gettokens` function creates a new has map every time. This gets then assigned to the `tokens` attribute an overrides the last one there. Thus in the end you wind up with only the last hash map containing the last token.

The solution would be to initialize the `tokens` attribute on `start()` or `read ()` and then just add the new token from the `gettokens` function - not creating a new instance of a `HashMap`.